# Need Help To Create DataBase?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I Going To Create A DataBase in SQL Server 2014 But I Have Problem .

A Need Use This Option : When The User Want To Register , Select Country , City Of The Country Display And Select it  .

For Example : When User Select The U.S.A , Display (NewYourk , Washington , . . . )

[**Pic Of Prog**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n38nX.png)

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
    OrderID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Fname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Lname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Tel VARCHAR(15),
    Counts INT NOT NULL, 
    DaysID INT NOT NULL,
    CountryID INT NOT NULL,
    CityID INT NOT NULL,
    Address VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (DaysID) REFERENCES WeekDays(DaysID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CountryID) REFERENCES Country(ContryID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CityID) REFERENCES City(CityID)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE WeekDays
(
    DaysID INT IDENTITY (10000001,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DaysName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
GO
CREATE TABLE Country
(
    CountryID INT IDENTITY (2000000,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CountryName VARCHAR(100)
)
CREATE TABLE City
(
    CityID INT IDENTITY (2000000,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CityName VARCHAR(100)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you must have a FOREIGN KEY of CountryID in City table so that you can Fetch the cities of USA

```
CREATE TABLE City
(
    CityID INT IDENTITY (2000000,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CityName VARCHAR(100)
    CountryID INT 
    FOREIGN KEY (CountryID ) REFERENCES Country(CountryID )
)

--FETCH RECORDS

SELECT * FORM City
WHERE CountryID=1 -- OR whatever the id of the Country
```

Comment: You don't need any foreign keys to FETCH rows... (They are only there to make sure data is consistent... So keep it!)